# Change multiple item images when pressed

Tags: angular, mobile, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid

New to ionic 2, Looking for implementing multi select check box feature on top of ion-list >> ion-item >> avatar image. Meaning, in a contact list , user should be able to press and hold and select multiple contacts from that list. any css built-in or custom approach to change avatar image to avatar image with check box and select?

(Please let me know if this is not clear, thanks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way is probably not having a checkbox (or faking it with css) and then in you component create a `selectedList` which will keep track of which avatars are clicked on (assuming they have f.e. an `id` as identifier).

Html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic 2
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="has-header">
  <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let contact of contactList">
      <ion-avatar (click)="clickedAvatar(contact.id)"
         [class]="isInArray(contact.id) ? 'selected' : 'not-selected'"
            item-left>
            <img src="https://pickaface.net/assets/images/slides/slide2.png"/> <!-- get image from contact object --> 
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{contact.name}}</h2> <!-- etc -->
   </ion-item>
</ion-list> 
</ion-content>
```

ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  templateUrl:"page1.html"
})
export class Page1{
  contactList: any[];

  selectedContacts: any[];

    constructor(){
       this.selectedContacts = [];
       this.contactList = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Steve"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mark"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Lauren"
  }];
    }

    clickedAvatar(id: number){

      console.log(this.selectedContacts);
       if(this.isInArray(id)){
         let index = this.selectedContacts.indexOf(id);

         this.selectedContacts.splice(index,1);
       }else{
          this.selectedContacts.push(id);
          console.log(this.selectedContacts.indexOf(id));
       }
    }

    isInArray(id: number): boolean{
      let check: boolean = false;
      for(let contactId of this.selectedContacts){
         if(contactId == id){ 
           check = true;
         }
      }
      return check;
    }
}
```

css

```
.selected img{
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

The (click) event will execute on a tap and on a longer press. If you want to use only tap or the actual press and hold you should change `(click)` to `(press)` or `(tap)`.

(wrote this from memory so might be incorrect classnames or a typo somewhere :) ). (I'll try to create a plunkr)

Comment: Thanks @Ivaro18 for your quick response. Great ! it would be nice to have a plunkr. I will see...

Comment: Is this what you meant or did you mean something else?

Comment: Awesome @lvaro18. I will try this and let you know how it works... Marking it as answer... Thanks again

Comment: No problem, if it doesn't work or you've got a question let me know :)

Comment: If I have a additional question in this context, can I extend in this thread or post a new question

Comment: Depends on how similar it is, better open up a new one since this is marked as 'answered'

Comment: Thanks @ivaro18 This solution works great. Tried to change icon as check mark on (press) , the "selected"  style  works well for opacity, but not for changing img. Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: Alright, create a new question and post the url here :)